# how to add parents name in an object (got parent count )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a object in which it property have **parent count** and **parent names**. I am able to count the parents ..But I want to add the parent name in my code..
Here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/ood2ezvz/11/

Code

```
function getParentCount(nodes) {
    var parent = {}, o = {};
    nodes.forEach(function (n) {
        parent[n.node_from] = parent[n.node_from] || [];
        n.children.forEach(function (a) {
            parent[a.node_to] = parent[a.node_to] || [];
            parent[a.node_to].push(n.node_from);
        });
    });
    Object.keys(parent).forEach(function (k) { o[k] = parent[k].length; });
    return o;
}
```

**my output**

```
{11: 0, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1}
```

**Expected out put**

```
{
11:{count:0,parent:[]},
12:{count:1,parent:['11']},
13:{count:1,parent:['12']},
14:{count:1,parent:['13']},
15:{count:2,parent:['13','14']},
16:{count:1,parent:['15']},
17:{count:1,parent:['15']},
18:{count:1,parent:['15']},
19:{count:1,parent:['18']},
}
```

Comment: Why?  is it important?

Comment: to get more info  of node ..

Comment: Ideally a child shouldn't need to know about it's parent. It's a sign of something being backwards in your design if you need this.

Comment: yup I know ..but for more info of node I need this..

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
Object.keys(parent).forEach(function (k) { o[k] = parent[k].length; });
```

By :

```
Object.keys(parent).forEach(function (k) { 
    o[k] = {};
    o[k]['count'] = parent[k].length; 
    o[k]['parent'] = parent[k]; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest converting your structure to something more usable. Since it seems to  be a directed graph, a natural representation will be the list of pairs `[from, to]`:

```
graph = []

node.forEach(n =>
    n.children.forEach(c =>
        graph.push([n.node_from, c.node_to])
    )
)
```

Now you can easily find preceding and following nodes for every given node:

```
nodes_from = n => graph.filter(v => v[0] === n).map(v => v[1])
console.log(nodes_from(15)) // [ 16, 17, 18 ]

nodes_to = n => graph.filter(v => v[1] === n).map(v => v[0])
console.log(nodes_to(15)) // [ 13, 14 ]
```